# Blurry PDF text when viewed using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The text on the PDF files is always blurry when I open the link via Chrome. How do I fix this? I have tried changing the "size of text, apps, and other items" to various values but the font of the PDF files is always still blurrier when viewed using Chrome compared to downloading it and viewing it using a PDF Viewer.

Comment: Have you tested other browsers?

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you! It is much clearer using firefox. Is there a way for me to fix the font issue on Chrome or am I forced to switch to Firefox when reading pdfs ?